# first formal parameter to 'operator new' must be 'size_t'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, size-t

i am getting this error "first formal parameter to 'operator new' must be 'size_t'"
when i try to compile smth like this:

```
void* operator new(MyStd::UInt);
```

I use visual studio 2013 express running on a 64 bit machine.

Does anyone know, why this error occurs?

If you need further information, pls let me know...this project is huge!

Comment: The error message could hardly be any clearer. What aspect of the error are you failing to understand?

Comment: `MyStd`, a.k.a. not standard at all, hmm?

Comment: What exactly would you like us to say, other than that the "first formal parameter to 'operator new' must be 'size_t'"? Because the answer is that the first formal parameter to 'operator new' must be 'size_t'. Have you considered making the first formal parameter to 'operator new' a 'size_t'? If you make the first formal parameter to your 'operator new' a 'size_t', then you won't get the error message saying that the first formal parameter to 'operator new' must be 'size_t'.

Comment: Perhaps MyStd::UInt happened to be size_t in a 32 bit world, but no longer is in a 64-bit world.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly what the error message says: the first parameter must be of type `size_t`.

That is exactly what [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) suggests.

Comment: Yes thats true...but it already worked in the past...but now it doesnt anymore, and i dont get it why.

Comment: The fact that it worked in the past is an irrelevant accident.

Comment: @user3490546 Maybe in the past you were on a system where MySTD::UInt was std::size_t...

Comment: How can we comment on events of the past without you describing precisely what those former scenarios were? Wouldn't it be best for you to fix your broken code?

Answer (score 4):

The error says it all. First parameter of `operator new` must be of type `std::size_t` and you use some other type.

Comment: Well, formally, there is no type `std::size_t`, since `std::size_t` is required to be a typedef.  Practically, of course...

Answer (score 2):

Except that it can't, really, since `std::size_t` is a typedef;
it must have whatever type `std::size_t` is typedef'ed to.  The
easiest way of getting this is to declare it as `std::size_t`.
Re: it worked in the past: presumably, in the past,
`MyStd::UInt` was a typedef to the same type as `std::size_t`.
Now, one or the other typedef has changed.  Just declare the
first parameter of `operator new` to be `size_t`, and it will
automatically be the right type; declare it anything else, and
you're guessing how `std::size_t` is declared (which can change
from one implementation to another, or even from one version to
another).

Comment: Oki...i fixed it!

my cmake was wrong configured...i builded this project for a wrong device.

Now it works with my own typedef too...so size_t is not required!

Comment: @user3490546 `size_t` is "required".  Strictly speaking, the type must resolve (after typedefs) to the type `size_t` is declared as.  Practically speaking, the only practical, maintainable way to ensure this is to use `size_t`.